# Calculator, how can I store a value after click on plus symbol and give the sum after click on equal symbol?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm making a calculator but have a problem storing the value after clicking on the plus symbol and then choose another number to click on the equal symbol and get the result. Help me please! XP

```
let firstValue;
let secondValue;

document.querySelector('#addOperator').addEventListener('click', function() {
 if(document.querySelector('#addOperator')) {
  firstValue = document.querySelector('#output').textContent;
  // document.querySelector('#output').textContent = '';
  // console.log(firstValue);
  console.log(document.querySelector('#output').textContent);
 };
});

document.getElementById('equals').addEventListener('click', function() {
 if(document.querySelector('#output').textContent === firstValue) {
  secondValue = document.querySelector('#output').textContent;
  // console.log(secondValue);
  // document.querySelector('#output').textContent = add(firstValue, secondValue);
  console.log(document.querySelector('#output').textContent = add(firstValue, secondValue));
 };
});
```

My html document is this------------------------------------------------------------->

```
    <!-- Calculator display  -->
<div id="output">
  <!-- <div id="previous-operand"></div>
  <div id="current-operand"></div> -->
</div>

<button class="span-two" id="ac-color">AC</button>
<button id="clear-entry">CE</button>
<button id="divideOperator">÷</button>
<button class="number">7</button>
<button class="number">8</button>
<button class="number">9</button>
<button id="multiplyOperator">*</button>
<button class="number">4</button>
<button class="number">5</button>
<button class="number">6</button>
<button id="addOperator">+</button>
<button class="number">1</button>
<button class="number">2</button>
<button class="number">3</button>
<button id="subtractOperator">-</button>
<button class="number">0</button>
<button class="number">.</button>
<button class="span-two" id="equals">=</button>
```

Comment: You need to add program codes to capture the value of the button pressed if the user clicks the number buttons. It is not sufficient to just put program codes on + and = buttons.

Comment: You may refer to this : https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-an-html-calculator-app-from-scratch-using-javascript-4454b8714b98/

Comment: @ yeah I guess I will need to study that stuffs of data-*. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

this will work
i haven't added the add buttons but simply when you click on the operation, set a flag to check when you click calculate to say whether its an add/subtract etc

```
<input type="button" value="1" onclick="add(event)" />
<input type="button" value="2" onclick="add(event)"/>
<input type="button" value="3" onclick="add(event)"/>
<input type="button" value="4" onclick="add(event)"/>
<input type="button" value="Equals" onclick="calculate()"/>
...
<script>
var nums = [];

var add = function(e){
  nums.push(Number(e.target.value));
}

var calculate = function(){
  var res =0;
  if(nums.length > 0){  
    nums.forEach(function(num){
      res += num;
    });
  }
  alert(res);
  return res;
}
</script>
```